# Laravel Validator return error messages

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

```
public function search()
{
    if ($this->articleValidator->validateSearch(request())) {
        $response['response'] = TRUE;
        $response['data']['articles'] = $this->articleService->searchArticles(request()->keyword, request()->category, request()->from, request()->to);
        $response['html'] = view('partials/content-administrator-subsystem/articles', $response['data'])->render();
    } else {
        $response['response'] = $this->articleValidator->searchValidationErrors();
    }

    return json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

I have this function inside my ArticlesPageController. I send a POST request with axios to this method.

```
class ArticleValidator implements ArticleValidatorInterface
{
    protected $searchValidator;

    /**
     * Validates articles search request
     *
     * @param request - Request object
     * @returns true/false if validation succeeded
     */
    public function validateSearch($request)
    {
        $this->searchValidator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'category' => 'array|min:1|exists:categories,id',
            'from' => 'date',
            'to' => 'date|after_or_equal:from'
        ]);

        return !$this->searchValidator->fails();
    }

    /**
     * Returns search validation errors
     *
     * @return validation errors or null if everything went well
     */
    public function searchValidationErrors()
    {
        if ($this->searchValidator) {
            print_r($this->searchValidator->errors()->getMessages());
            return $this->searchValidator->errors();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is validator class.

The problem is, if validator fails, I get such return:

```
{ 
    "response": { 
        "to": ["validation.after_or_equal"] 
    } 
}
```

As you can see, it is validation rule that has failed, the problem is, that I need to get actual messages not the rule that has failed.

I know that in normal flow, I can do `return redirect()->withErrors($errors)` and in a view I would get an $errors array, but now, when it is an AJAX call, I cant do any redirects. so how can I get actual messages and return them back?

Comment: did you try to return `$this->searchValidator->messages();`

Comment: Did you realize you have a `print_r()` inside `searchValidationErrors()`?

Comment: If you remove the ``print_r`` and return ``$this->searchValidator->messages()`` instead of ``$this->searchValidator->errors()`` you should get desired results.

Comment: print_r was for debugging purposes, I changed everything as you said, but same results

Comment: Look in your [`resources/lang/en/validation.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.5.0/resources/lang/en/validation.php) language file. Is there an entry for `after_or_equal`?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic, when you use the `validate()` method and your request was an AJAX one, you get the errors in JSON format in the response. You can see another way to use the Validator here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#automatic-redirection.

You may have to check for the corresponding version of the documentation because there were slight variations over time, but this should give you a kickstart.